# Can Wireshark display info about the size of the data in a POST request?

Tags: size, http-post, wireshark

As the heading states:
Can Wireshark display info about the size of the data in an HTTP POST request?

It would be even better if I could see the size of specific fields submitted in the post data.

How/can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

> Can Wireshark display info about the size of the data in an HTTP POST request?

If by "data" you mean the posted data, then, if the POST request has a Content-Length: header, yes, it can - look for that header.

> It would be even better if I could see the size of specific fields submitted in the post data.

That's not so easy, although you can get the individual fields of an "XXX=yyy" item as "urlencoded-form.key" and "urlencoded-form.value" if the Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded.